# Test a Symfony REST API using Behat / Mink : prb with POST request

Tags: rest, functional-programming, behat, mink, symfony3.x

My challenge here is to find the best way to test a Symfony (3.4) API application using Behat/Mink for functionnal test, in my CICD platform.

Because my testing processes must be called in a shell script, all the tests must be very linear. I have no way to start a standalone webserver like Apache or the PHP/Symfony webserver. Also, Docker is not an option.

For the moment, I can successfully test the GET verbs of the API using the Mink syntax :

```
-- file test.feature 
@function1
  Scenario Outline: Test my api
    When I go to "/api/v1/hello"
    Then the response is JSON
```

The "I go to" instruction is implemented by Mink (http://docs.behat.org/en/v2.5/cookbook/behat_and_mink.html) and it emulates a GET request only. When this instruction is called by BeHat, the app Symfony kernel is "spawned" and the "api/v1/hello" method is called internally : there is no network trafic, no TCP connection, there is no need for a dedicated webserver (apache, or the symfony standalone server). It looks like Behat is emulating a webserver and start by itself the Symfony app it its own user space.

Now I want to test the POST verbs of my API, with a json payload, but unfortunally Mink do not have other verbs than GET.

I have read some articles over the web (keyword : behat test post api) but all I have seen is based on a Guzzl/Curl client. So a real client-to-server connection is made to http://localhost and a real webserver have to respond to the request.

I want the Symfony API to be called internally without using an other webserver.
Is there a way to do that ? How to test a Symfony REST API and specially the  POST verb without needing a standalone server to reply ?

Thank you.

Comment: Use Guzzle with Behat.

Comment: Guzzle or Curl is not an option : I dont want my Behat tests to create a real HTTP connection to a running webserver. Remember, i'm not able to start Apache on this server. The CICD functionnal test process should not need  a running webserver. We start Behat test in command line, not inside a webserver.
I found a solution by using, in the FeatureContext.php file, something like `$client = $this->getSession()->getDriver()->getClient(); $req = $client->request('POST'...)
` I will provide a more detailed working code later.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do a functional test of a POST API, with BeHat, without a local running webserver :

test.feature :

```
@function1
  Scenario Outline: Test my api
  Given I have the payload
    """
    { "data":"object"}
    """
    When I request "POST /api/v1/post"
    Then the response is JSON
```

The featureContext file implement two functions :

- "I Have The Payload" : See here https://github.com/philsturgeon/build-apis-you-wont-hate/blob/master/chapter8/app/tests/behat/features/bootstrap/FeatureContext.php
- "I request" : based on code provided by philsturgeon just above, I modify it to have something like that :

```php
/**
 * @When /^I request "(GET|PUT|POST|DELETE|PATCH) ([^"]*)"$/
 */
public function iRequest($httpMethod, $resource)
{
    $this->lastResponse = $this->lastRequest = null;
    $this->iAmOnHomepage();
    $method = strtoupper($httpMethod);
    $components = parse_url($this->getSession()->getCurrentUrl());
    $baseUrl = $components['scheme'].'://'.$components['host'];
    $this->requestUrl = $baseUrl.$resource;
    $formParams = json_decode($this->requestPayload, true);
    $formParamsList = [];
    foreach($formParams as $param => $value) {
        $formParamsList[$param] = json_encode($value);
    }
    // Construct request
    $headers = [
        'Accept'=>'application/json',
        'Content-Type'=>'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    ];
    try {
        // Magic is here : allow to simulate any HTTP verb
        $client = $this->getSession()->getDriver()->getClient();
        $client->request(
            $method,
            $this->requestUrl,
            $formParamsList,
            [],
            $headers,
            null);
    } catch (BadResponseException $e) {
        $response = $e->getResponse();
        // Sometimes the request will fail, at which point we have
        // no response at all. Let Guzzle give an error here, it's
        // pretty self-explanatory.
        if (null === $response) {
            throw $e;
        }
        $this->lastResponse = $e->getResponse();
        throw new \Exception('Bad response.');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Mink then it is quite easy

```
class FeatureContext extends RawMinkContext
{
    /**
     * @When make POST request to some Uri
     */
    public function makePostRequestToSomeUri(): void
    {
        $uri = '/some-end-point';

        /** @var \Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Client $client */
        $client = $this->getSession()->getDriver()->getClient();
 
        $postParams = [];
        $files = [];
        $serverParams = [];
        $rawContent = '';

        $client->request(
            \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::METHOD_POST, 
            $uri, 
            $postParams, 
            $files, 
            $serverParams, 
            $rawContent
        );

        /** @var \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response $response */
        $response = $client->getResponse();

        //...
    }
}
```